# Prevent Infragistics use ig_common

Tags: asp.net, .net, infragistics

We have an old ASP.NET web application that's using Infragistics components, and needs a virtual directory "ig_common" to access javascripts and images.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior? And, for example, import all Infra's javascripts and images in the webapp?

Comment: Look at this post: [Using Version Upgrade Utility](https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/web-using-version-upgrade-utility)

Comment: @Jackdaw Thanks but this post doesn't resolve our problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Upgrade to a new version of Infragistics.

Comment: We cannot upgrade to a new version, otherwise we would have already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those like us who can't upgrade, we've found this from: https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-asp-net-web-forms/3797/ig_common-and-javascript/19780

In web.config,  in the configSections, add:

```
<section name="infragistics.web" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,System, Version=x.x.xxxx.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

After that, add a section to indicate where the images and scripts have to be found:

```
<infragistics.web imageDirectory="~/images/Images" javaScriptDirectory="~/scripts"/>
```

I hope this can help others.